# Spring Boot 2 can't connect to Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to use the Lettuce driver with Spring Boot 2 and Spring Data Redis (both latest). I can't connect to Redis, I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.lettuce.core.KeyValue
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 148 common frames omitted
```

I want to use the reactive connection so I am overriding the connectionFactory, config class

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    fun reactiveRedisConnection(redisConnectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory): ReactiveRedisConnection {
        return redisConnectionFactory.reactiveConnection
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisConnectionFactory(): LettuceConnectionFactory {
        return LettuceConnectionFactory()
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
## Redis config
spring.redis.host=192.168.99.100
spring.redis.port=32769
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:${springBootVersion}")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis")
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.5")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else bumping into same issue, you gonna need to add the lettuce dependency separately.

```
compile("io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.0.3.RELEASE")
```

Still not picking application.properties will sort it out later.